# Returning an array of data from database in a java method

Tags: java, arrays, database, methods

I'm trying to get the values from a database and insert them into an array and return, but it gives me an error: "cannot find symbol for variable `str` in return statement".

```
public class getDates {
public static Date[] Dates(){

   Connection con = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String db = "GreetingCard";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";
    try{
      Class.forName(driver);
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, user, pass);
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select date from profile");
      ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
      int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
      Date[] str = new Date[columnCount];
      int a=0;
    //getting the dates from database to an array

      while(rs.next()){

      str[a++]=rs.getDate("date");
    }

    }
     catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
      }
     //returning the array str

    return str;
}
}
```

Comment: think about what the method should return when an expedition is thrown and caught. An empty array? Null? should it throw a new exception?

Comment: tried putting return statement in try block and return null in catch block.it worked.Thankss!! :)

Answer (score 1):

str is declared inside your `try` block. You need to move the return inside that block.

As a side note, it is almost never a good idea to `System.out.println` an exception

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.i have tried putting the return statement in the try block but then i get an error missing return statement in the method

Comment: I guess I assumed too much ;) remove the try - catch entirely, and let your method throw (the correct) Exceptions, and you should be good

Comment: It should work as well.tried putting return statement in try block and return null in catch block.it worked.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that everything declared within `try/catch` statements can potentially *not* happen—the compiler is trying to prevent this.

For example, if you have a method with the following structure (as you said in another comment):

```
public boolean trueOrFalse()
{
    try
    {
        somethingExceptional();
        boolean result = true;
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        doSomething(e);
    }
}
```

You are telling the compiler that your method will return a boolean, but if `somethingExceptional()` happens, and an exception is thrown, nothing will be returned because the rest of the try will be skipped!

So instead you should define your variable before the try statement, give it a default value, and return *after* the catch statement:

```
public boolean trueOrFalse()
{
    boolean result = false;

    try
    {
        somethingExceptional();
        result = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This way, you ensure that even if `somethingExceptional()` does happen to throw, something will be returned from the method.

Or you can instead add a `throws` to the method signature and get rid of the `try/catch`.

Comment: Since array is initialized inside the while loop i get the error in return statement "variable str might not have been initialized".I tried putting "return str" in try block and "return null" in catch block.it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare you array after bloc `try` and return it after bloc `catch`.

Try this

```
public class getDates {
    public static Date[] Dates(){

       Connection con = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String db = "GreetingCard";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";
        // STR declaration outside try catch blocs
        Date[] str = new Date[10 /*any value > 0 */];
        try{
          Class.forName(driver);
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, user, pass);
          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select date from profile");
          ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
          int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
          // STR instantiation 
          str = new Date[columnCount];
          int a=0;
          //getting the dates from database to an array
          while(rs.next()){
            str[a++]=rs.getDate("date");
          }

        }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
        }
         //returning the array str
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: then i get the error "cannot find symbol" for str in return statement and also in str[a++]=rs.getDate("date")

Comment: Try this code, I think that it will work. @user2700115

Comment: get the error in return statement "variable str might not have been initialized".I tried putting "return str" in try block and "return null" in catch block.it worked :)

Comment: You can also initialize the str array with any length the reinitialize it with columnCount.

Answer (score 0):

Seek the second line from the bottom ,where does the variate STR declare?
Before use STR,declare and initialize it.
While your declaring is in the Try/Catch block , the compiler couldn't find it.
Just move the declaring out of the Try/Catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.I tried this..It worked :)

```
 public class getDates {
  public static Date[] Dates(){

   Connection con = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String db = "GreetingCard";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";
    try{
      Class.forName(driver);
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, user, pass);
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select date from profile");
      ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
      int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
      Date[] str = new Date[columnCount];
      int a=0;
      while(rs.next()){

      str[a++]=rs.getDate("date");
    }

      return str;
    }
     catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
         return null;
      }

  }
 }
```